# Error Add:Field 'sku' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error:

```
Error Add:Field 'sku' doesn't have a default value
```

Where `sku` is a cloumn inside `products` table. I tried the next options:

`NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`
`NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL`
`NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` `DEFAULT '0'` `DEFAULT ''` but none working, still the same error.

This is the table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE `features_cuts_product_values` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `features_cuts_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=hebrew;
```

I've been over the whole internet, I searched StackOverflow but found nothing that solved my issue.

Why is it happening and how do I solve it?

Comment: show your code for table creation

Comment: Also include the query which generated the error message.

Comment: @scaisEdge I added the tablle creation code, I will upload the query in a sec, I need to find it since it's a website that has been passed to me

Comment: OK...but that create table statement still won't generate the error.  What did you do exactly to generate the error?

Comment: You are trying to insert a row with sku null  ..

Comment: Doesn't this error means `sku` does not have a default value and I simply need to add one?

Comment: It indicates that you are trying to insert a record at runtime without a value for a non-nullable field. Basically it is saying, "you tried to insert a record into this table, but you didn't provide a value for a mandatory field, and the table definition doesn't have a default value for me to fall back on."

Comment: I just found out I have more `sku`s columns in other tables, I need to find the one who's making the error and reconfigure it, right?

Comment: Apparently  the programmer who built the whole database used `sku` as column name in much more then one table so I have to go through all of them. except of going through them one by one is there a better, faster way to do it?